# Flutter chat application always load the first time a conversation is oppend

Tags: flutter, sockets, chat, flutter-streambuilder

I am trying to create a flutter chat app, but I am facing some troubles.
I want my chat app to behave similar to Facebook Messenger or Instagram chat.
And I am noticing that in these apps when ever i open a conversation the chat do not load, they are there already.
In my app
When I use streams socket connection to emit response and then adding it as a list and showing it in the list view every time a user open a conversation that make the screen load and show the messages, I can't see this behavior in the modern chat apps. What should I do to be able to have the same behavior.

I don't think that I'm able to load data locally and from stream at the same time, when I try to add a local data to stream it never shows, but  when i emit it withe socket it shows

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    getDatawhenPageFirstLoad = Provider.of<Conversation>(context, listen: false)
        .getConversationIfexist(widget.userid);
    mapKey = Provider.of<Conversation>(context, listen: false)
        .findInLocalMap(widget.userid);
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

StreamBuilder(
          stream: Provider.of<Conversation>(context, listen: false)
              .streamController
              .stream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ChatModel>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting &&
                snapshot.data != null) {
              return Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                child: Center(
                  child: LoadingAnimationWidget.staggeredDotsWave(
                      color: Colors.blue, size: 20),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              if (snapshot.error != null) {
                return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    reverse: true,
      
                    itemCount:  
  
                        snapshot.data!.length ,
                         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var getData = mapKey == 0
                          ? snapshot.data![index]
                          : chatrommsfromMap[mapKey]!.chats[index];
                      return singelMessage(
                          isMine: getData.is_mine,
                          messageText:getData.message_text
                          );
                    });
              }
            }
          },
        );
```

my socket connection

```
 Future<void> getConversationIfexist(int user_id) async {
    var jwt = await storage.read(key: "token");
    var userid = await storage.read(key: "id");
    List<ChatModel> _chats = [];
    final IO.Socket socket = IO.io(
        'http://192.168.0.5:8080/chatRomms',
        // 'http://172.20.10.5:8080/chatRomms',
        IO.OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket'])
            .setExtraHeaders({"token": jwt})
            .disableAutoConnect()
            .setQuery({"token": jwt})
            .setAuth({"token": jwt})
            .build());

    socket.connect();
    print(user_id);
    socket.emit("findUserConversationById", user_id);
    socket.on(
        "result",
        (data) => {
              print(data["conversation"]['messages']),
              if (data != null)
                {
                  for (var ii in data["conversation"]['messages'])
                    {
                      _chats.add(ChatModel(
                          id: ii['id'],
                          message_text: ii['message_text'],
                          is_seen: ii['is_seen'],
                          user_id: ii['user_id'],
                          conversation_id: ii['conversation_id'],
                          updatedAt: ii['updatedAt'],
                          is_mine: data['user']["id"] == int.parse(userid!)
                              ? true
                              : false))
                    }
                  streamController.sink.add(_chats),
                  notifyListeners(),
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that not only a single person manage those apps and those apps use native IOS and Android development kits which means faster and far better performance than flutter.

Furthermore, I might be wrong but in addition to my previous statement, those chat pages you speak of in Facebook and so on, they actually load but the loading process is too fast that you don't see it. You can actually see this in your flutter app.

For example there are some things that if you load on an old phone through your flutter app, it takes time while on a faster phone (say an Iphone 13) it is almost instant.

Besides flutter runs all its functions on a single thread (Main thread) which means everything is executed sequentially.

You can search for  ** The Boring flutter show** on Youtube to better understand..

Answer (score 0):

You should keep old messages in local and load it while opening the app. Meantime while launching the app try to sync your existing local messages with updated new messages.

```
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/flutter-offline-first-with-flutter-data-62bad61097be#:~:text=Flutter%20Data%20is%20a%20package,to%20the%20API%20becomes%20available.
```